# Build for iphone appstore from one account; publish using another

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have built an iphone app for another company. Now they want that the app is published using their account. Is there any possibility, that I can build and share the app using my account's certificate and they publish using their account.

If not, how can I share the project with them, or any other possibilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this a few times, and for the life of me I can't think how I did it. I know that most people just create a new user account on their Mac and use the new company's developer profile on that account.

I didn't do it that way. I believe that I may have just swapped the developer accounts when needing to publish. Delete the certificates from keychain and add the other company's one. You won't have to do this much, just the few times you have to publish to the app store. You can backup your current developer profile and re-load it when you have finished. If you back up the other company's dev profile too then it won't be too much hassle when you switch.

If they don't want to give you access to their developer profile then you will have to send them an archived copy of the app. You can go to `Product` and then `Archive` (as if you were creating an app store version). When you go to "share" you can create an XCode archive which you can then send to them and they can import into XCode their end and sign with their own certificates and such. This is obviously the easiest option if the other company know what they're doing. Otherwise this may be the most difficult option!

As far as I know there is no way you can build it for submission and then sign it with another account's developer profile. I also don't think there is any way to run multiple developer profiles under one user account on Mac, although this is something you could look into and see if there is any info on ways around this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where is `Product` menu which you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: In my XCode its in the menu bar next to "File, Edit, View, Navigate, Editor ..."

Comment: Thnx for the direction, I did it by backing up my current profiles and certificates, and deleted them from keychain. And used the certificate and profile from the company's account. After creating the required appstore archive, I reverted back to my original developer's profile and certificate.

Thnx a lot.